# connecting to another server and getting details

Tags: unix, ssh

I am  currently working on one  unix issue my requirements are I am in `x` server I want to ssh and connect to `y` server, change to another directory and find one file. Here `x` and `y` are some ip addresses.

I tried to run this command:

```
ssh y -l lafter | cd Product | find . -name "hemant"
```

Note  currently I am  in `x` server: the problem with above command is it is displaying the `x`  server file details but not the `y` server file  details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not pipe the commands together. Instead pass the arguments to `y` as a string:

```
ssh y -l lafter 'cd Product && find . -name "hemant"'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using pipes instead of running a command on your server `y`:

```
ssh username@y 'cd Product && find . -name "hemant"'
```

In the above command I open a session to the server `y` for a user `username` (if no key is configured you need to insert the password for `username`)

In your case, with:

```
ssh y -l lafter | cd Product | find . -name "hemant"
```

you first run on `x` the command `find . -name "hemant"`, then the output of this command is piped to the `stdin` of the command `cd` (and here you probably get an error), and finally the output of `cd` is piped to the `stdin` of `ssh`. This sequence of pipes is completely useless.